# Read hex file, convert to string and load to listBox

Tags: c#, listview, hex

I want the listBox to display the IDs stored at a file. The IDs are in hexadecimal value.

I am stuck trying to load the file and converting the HEX to ASCII, so the listBox can load it.
The file also contains some more information, like item name, item level, and such...

Here is a sample of the file:

```
00000000h: 50 12 00 00 2F D9 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; P.../Ù..........
00000010h: 46 65 61 74 68 65 72 20 45 61 72 72 69 6E 67 00 ; Feather Earring.
00000020h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000030h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000040h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000050h: 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 07 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000060h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 88 00 00 ; ............¸ˆ..
00000070h: 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 ; ............ ...
00000080h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000090h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000a0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000000f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000100h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000110h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000120h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000130h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000140h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000150h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000160h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000170h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000180h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000190h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001a0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000001f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000200h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000210h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000220h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000230h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000240h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000250h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000260h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000270h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000280h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000290h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002a0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000002f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000300h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000310h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000320h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000330h: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4A 61 64 65 20 45 61 72 ; ........Jade Ear
00000340h: 72 69 6E 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ring............
00000350h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000360h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000370h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 ; ................
00000380h: 07 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000390h: 00 00 00 00 20 A1 07 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; .... ¡..........
000003a0h: 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; .... ...........
000003b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000003c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000003d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000003e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000003f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000400h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000410h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000420h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000430h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000440h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000450h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000460h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000470h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000480h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000490h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004a0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000004f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000500h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000510h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000520h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000530h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000540h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000550h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000560h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000570h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000580h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000590h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005a0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005b0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005c0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005d0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005e0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
000005f0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000600h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000610h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000620h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000630h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000640h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000650h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
```

Ignore the "50 12 00 00 2F D9 01 00" at the beggining, that is file version and other irrelevant data, what i want to parse into the listBox is the item ID "01" that is right after the version of the file.

The next item ID is at "00000330h" and the value is "02". Towards the end of the files you can see that there is ID "03"...

**EDIT:**

OK, now I am loading the file and reading the Item's section inside of it, but I have no clue how to load the IDs into the listBox...
The IDs are separated from each other by 807 bytes, so every 807 bytes there is an ID.

Here is how I am loading the file's section

```
    int itemSectionStart = 0x00000000;
    int itemSectionEnd = 0x002e11e0;

    FileStream fstream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx.dec", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    long length = fstream.Length;

    breader.BaseStream.Position = itemSectionStart;
    byte[] itemSection = breader.ReadBytes(itemSectionEnd);
```

Comment: This so reminds me of PC save game files and having ELITE with TONS of credits :)

Comment: haha yeah, it's something like that :P

Comment: don't understand why do you want hex to ascii conversion ? Is this hex dump just visual presentation of file in some hex viewer ?

Comment: When I press the "load" button, the listBox has to load all the item IDs. The IDs are in HEX value and I want the values to be in a readable form, ASCII. When it gets to the item ID "061A85", it would display "400005" rather than the HEX value.


edit: the dump is taken from UltraEdit's view of the file

Comment: Maybe you don't have to code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttXLokNi0_Q (try to figure out what editor he used)...

Comment: I added some code to the post. Still trying to figure out how to work this out.

Comment: If the hex you posted is accurate, your IDs are actually separated by 808 bytes, which makes far more sense anyway.  My answer should be applicable to what you want to do (filling in bits like 'NeedToByteSwap' and 'AddToListView' with relevant expressions).  If there is something you are not understanding, I can try and clarify for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally accomplished what I was looking for!
Here is the approach I took to make it work: (Might not be pretty, but it works!)

```
private string hex2dec(string hexString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(long.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    return sb.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numRecords = 3737;
    int itemSectionStart = 0x00000008;
    int itemSectionEnd = 0x002e11ec;

    using (FileStream str = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx.dec"))
    {
        BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(str);
        breader.BaseStream.Position = itemSectionStart;
        byte[] itemSection = breader.ReadBytes(itemSectionEnd);

        int j = 0;
        int k = j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++)
        {
            string id = BitConverter.ToString(itemSection, 808 * k++, 7);
            string[] strArrayID = id.Split(new char[] { '-' });
            string reversedID = strArrayID[6] + strArrayID[5] + strArrayID[4] + strArrayID[3] + strArrayID[2] + strArrayID[1] + strArrayID[0];
            listBox1.Items.Add(this.hex2dec(reversedID));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your fixation with treating this as a Hex string.  Do you intend to use a hex string somewhere else?  Your text editor displays your data in hex as a convenience for you, but the underlying id data has nothing to do with either hex or ASCII.  If your code is working, that's great, but I think you are doing a lot more work than you really need to be doing.

Comment: if it ain't broke, don't fix it lol
it's working just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know how to locate the IDs you want in the file, and you know their width (e.g. you know they're each 4 bytes comprising an Int32), you can use C#'s [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class, which takes a byte array and an index and gives you back the corresponding numeric type.  You may have to swap things around if endianness is an issue.

Read your file into a byte array, use BitConverter at each offset you care about, convert the numbers to strings, and load up your ListView.

```
int startIndex = 8;
int recordStride = 128;
int numRecords = 4;

using (FileStream str = File.OpenRead("myfile.ext")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
        byte[] data = new byte[4];
        str.Seek(startIndex + recordStride * i, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        str.Read(data, 0, 4);
        if (NeedToByteSwap)
            Array.Reverse(data);

        int id = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        AddToListView(id.ToString());
    }
}
```

Fill in or calculate your starting parameters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound so much like the data is in Hex format - sounds more like that's just the representation that the editor gave you.  Instead it seems more probably that the file is a straight binary dump with text encoded as ASCII byte stream.

In which case you'd want to isolate a byte[] range that represents the chars (is there a clear definition of what delimits records, names etc?).  Feed that to 
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx)

One of the GetString overloads will convert the byte range to ASCII text.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx)

Comment: the IDs are 807 bytes apart from each other and in the middle there is other data about each item.
The values are in HEX, but they are "reversed", so the file would display "32 DF 14 3C" reversed hex value, which really is "3C 14 DF 32" and would translate to "1008000818" in decimal form.